# Matching result not writing into file

Tags: bash, shell

I have`users.txt` as input file like below format.

```
rajesh.kumar@company.com
rhmn@company.com
mkkumar@company.com
manish.panday@company.com
daniel.m@company.com
jain@company.com
abul@company.com
aditi@company.com
aditya.s@company.com
```

Below script to read the `users.txt` file line by line and write only the matching user mail address along with row into the csv file.

```
#!/bin/bash

Input_file="users.txt"
Output_file="result.csv"
Match_list="$(command_to_get_match_user)"
Email="$(echo "$Match_list" | awk -F '|' '{print $4}' | tr -d '[:space:]')"

while read line; do
  if [[ "$line" == *"$Email"* ]]; then
    echo "$line" >> "$Output_file"
  fi
done < "$Input_file"
```

My command `Match_list=` in the above script provides the below output during the run time.

```
1320 | | Rajesh Kumar | rajesh.kumar@company.com | live
1584 | | A.K.M. Rahman | rhmn@company.com | live
1503 | | Mukesh Kumar | mkkumar@company.com | live
1279 | | Aayush Jain | aayush.jain@company.com | live
1597 | | Abul Hasan Md Osama | abul.osama@company.com | live
1660 | | Aditi Singpuri | aditi.singpuri@company.com | live
1570 | | Aditya Jain | aditya.jain@company.com | live
```

Currently above script is not writing the matched result in to file.

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: If those are real names, they probably should not be posted like that. Consider replacing them with fake names.

Comment: @M.Becerra - Those are not real names, all are some sample names.

Comment: You did not show how users.txt exactly looks like. Do a `cat users.txt` and show what is displayed.

Comment: please have a look it is added in the question section already. `users.txt` consist the users email address.

Comment: Did you try to write directly into a file? `echo "$line" >> "result.csv"`, this seems to work for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

Given this input:

```
$ head -100 users.txt data.txt
==> users.txt <==
rajesh.kumar@company.com
rhmn@company.com
mkkumar@company.com
manish.panday@company.com
daniel.m@company.com
jain@company.com
abul@company.com
aditi@company.com
aditya.s@company.com

==> data.txt <==
1320 | | Rajesh Kumar | rajesh.kumar@company.com | live
1584 | | A.K.M. Rahman | rhmn@company.com | live
1503 | | Mukesh Kumar | mkkumar@company.com | live
1279 | | Aayush Jain | aayush.jain@company.com | live
1597 | | Abul Hasan Md Osama | abul.osama@company.com | live
1660 | | Aditi Singpuri | aditi.singpuri@company.com | live
1570 | | Aditya Jain | aditya.jain@company.com | live
```

This seems to be what you're trying to do (using any awk):

```
# cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

command_to_get_match_user() { cat data.txt; }

Input_file="users.txt"
Output_file="result.csv"

command_to_get_match_user |
awk '
    { sub(/\r$/,"") }
    NR == FNR {
        emails[$1]
        next
    }
    $4 in emails
' "$Input_file" FS=' *[|] *' - > "$Output_file"
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
```

```
$ cat result.csv
1320 | | Rajesh Kumar | rajesh.kumar@company.com | live
1584 | | A.K.M. Rahman | rhmn@company.com | live
1503 | | Mukesh Kumar | mkkumar@company.com | live
```

The main difference between piping to the above `awk` script and [@Frvadona's grep solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75789774/1745001) is that this won't produce false matches if a target email address shows up in some other field in the input and it'll work on every Unix box, not just those with a grep that supports `-w` (GNU grep?). This script also would continue to work if `users.txt` contained a blank line while the pipe to grep would then print all input lines.

Given you mentioned not getting output when it looks like you should, there may be white space and/or [carriage returns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525/why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it) at the end of the lines in your emails list which is why I'm populating the array with `$1` instead of `$0` and have a `sub()` removing terminating CRs if present.

I'm not suggesting you redefine `command_to_get_match_user` to be what I show - I just had to have some definition for it to test with.

Answer (score 1):

You might get some false positives but given the patterns and input files it should be accurate enough:

```bash
command_to_get_match_user | grep -wFf users.txt > result.csv
```

<sup>**note:** `grep -w` isn't standard but it is widely supported: GNU, BSD, Solaris (non-POSIX), AIX, HP-UX, etc...</sup>

Answer (score 1):

```
command_to_get_match_user(){
cat << EOF
1320 | | Rajesh Kumar | rajesh.kumar@company.com | live
1584 | | A.K.M. Rahman | rhmn@company.com | live
1503 | | Mukesh Kumar | mkkumar@company.com | live
1279 | | Aayush Jain | aayush.jain@company.com | live
1597 | | Abul Hasan Md Osama | abul.osama@company.com | live
1660 | | Aditi Singpuri | aditi.singpuri@company.com | live
1570 | | Aditya Jain | aditya.jain@company.com | live
EOF
}
```

**Output from users.txt**

```
awk -F'|' '
    NR==FNR{
        gsub(/^ *| *$/,"",$4)
        map[$4]
        next
    }
    ($0 in map)
' <(command_to_get_match_user) users.txt

rajesh.kumar@company.com
rhmn@company.com
mkkumar@company.com
```

**OR from command_to_get_match_user**

```
awk -F' *[|] * ' '
    NR==FNR{
        map[$0]
        next
    }
    ($4 in map)
'  users.txt <(command_to_get_match_user)


1320 | | Rajesh Kumar | rajesh.kumar@company.com | live
1584 | | A.K.M. Rahman | rhmn@company.com | live
1503 | | Mukesh Kumar | mkkumar@company.com | live
```

Answer (score 1):

With `sed` to extract email addresses from `command_to_get_match_user`, and `grep` to filter `users.txt`:

```
$ grep -Ff <(command_to_get_match_user |
sed -E 's/[[:space:]]*//g;s/^([^|]*\|){3}([^|]*).*/\2/') "$Input_file" > "$Output_file"

$ cat "$Output_file"
rajesh.kumar@company.com
rhmn@company.com
mkkumar@company.com
```

With GNU `sed`:

```
$ grep -Ff <(command_to_get_match_user |
sed -E 's/\s*//g;s/^([^|]*\|){3}([^|]*).*/\2/') "$Input_file" > "$Output_file"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the cleanest solution but it works

```bash
#!/bin/bash

Input_file="users.txt"
Output_file="result.csv"

while read line; do
   echo "$(command_to_get_match_user)" | grep $line | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "|" } ; {print $1,$3,$4}' | sed 's/   /,/g' >> $Output_file
done < $Input_file
```

Earlier you said you wanted the output as csv, but it looks like you edited your post to remove that. Should be easy enough to edit the code to get the output in any format you'd like

Comment: It was mistakenly updated. basically i need the output to be in `csv` file.

Comment: @user4948798 the code i posted should do that then.

Comment: That'll do different things depending on the content of and/or the name of the input files, the directory you run it from, environment settings, etc. and it'll run orders of magnitude slower than, say, an awk script that doesn't have those issues. You could run it through http://shellcheck.net to identify and fix some, but not all, of those issues (see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) for more on that).